# Remove background image from unactive menus by jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery and css to make menu. Page was load first time by default the first menu is active (background of active menu is dark) then if i click on other menu it should be dark and previous is normal.

Below the code that i have used to make menu

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tab_title').click(function() {
        $('.tab_title').removeClass('active').next();
        $(".tab_title_arrow").removeClass('active_arrow').next();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".tab_title_arrow").addClass('active_arrow'); 
    });
});
```

CSS code:

```
.tab_title {
    background: url(images/lft-white-repeat.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 50px;
    width:auto;
    float: left;    
}

.tab_title_arrow {
    background: url(images/white-aerow.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 21px;
    float: left;    
}

.active {
    background: url(images/tab-repeat-blue.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 50px;
    width:auto;
    float: left;    
}

.active_arrow {
    background: url(images/rgt-aerow-img.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 21px;
    float: left;
}

#workflow_menu {
    color:#000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style: none;
}

#workflow_menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="workflow_menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/tab-left.gif"  />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="subset_criterion">
            <div class="tab_title active">Subset Criterion
            </div>
            <div class="tab_title_arrow active_arrow">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="analytical_base_tables">
            <div class="tab_title">Analytical Base Tables
            </div>
            <div class="tab_title_arrow">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="data_exploration">
            <div class="tab_title">Data Exploration
            </div>
            <div class="tab_title_arrow">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="models">
           <div class="tab_title">Models
           </div>
           <div class="tab_title_arrow">
           </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="model_evalution">
            <div class="tab_title">Model Evalution
            </div>
            <div class="tab_title_arrow">
            </div>
        </a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/right-tab.gif"  />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am stuck on following: 
when "li" is active (clicked) the image (rgt-aerow-img.gif) should be hidden from all other "li". This image (rgt-aerow-img.gif) should be removed from all other "li" except from active "li". The imeages can be [viewed here](http://www.widevision.co.in/menu%20images/)

Comment: It’s a bit hard to understand what you’re after. Do you have the site somewhere online for us to have a look?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you're going for here.

What you want to do in your click function is target a class they all share or target it like $("#workflow_menu li"). You might want to make it $("#workflow_menu li a") if you want to target the link text. Or if you want the whole list item to be the link, add a display:block to the "a" in your "li". Anyways...

```
 $("#workflow_menu li").click(function(){ //when you click a list item.
    $("#workflow_menu li").css('background-color','white'); //change all to white
    $(this).css('background-color','black'); //change the one i click to black
});
```

It looks like you're using images, but it's the same basic idea. And actually, if you can do what you're doing with css, you'd be better off. Hope this helps.